# How to find questions having only given tag (and no other tags)?

Tags: support, tagging, search

For various reasons it is often useful to be able to find questions which have some given tag as a standalone tag. (For example, when discussing whether some tag is useful for this site or not. Or when burnination of some tags is discussed.)

Is it possible somehow find those questions which only contain some given tag?

Comment: I have posted this self-answered question since this thing seems to be useful for discussions about tags and it might be good to have this documented somewhere. (And also having a place where to find this information, when I forget how this is done.)

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is to search for questions tagged by a given tag sorted by relevance. This will *usually*<sup>1</sup> put questions with only this tag at the top. Example:
searching for "[calculus] is:question" and choosing relevance tab
https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5Bcalculus%5D%20is%3aquestion

There are also various SEDE queries for this purpose (for example, [this one](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/131389/finding-posts-tagged-only-with-one-given-tag?tagname=calculus)). However, data in the Data Explorer are only updated once a week.

I will also mention that there are some feature requests on meta.SE which ask for ability to search for questions having only a given tag:

- [Search for singleton tags on questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148977/search-for-singleton-tags-on-questions)
- [Searching for question having strictly a certain set of tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105548/searching-for-question-having-strictly-a-certain-set-of-tag)

---

<sup>1</sup>I did not find this documented anywhere on meta.SE, the only related question I found there was [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138089/searching-a-single-tag-by-relevance-bug-or-by-design). When I try something similar on SO, I do also get questions with mixed tags. For example, when I tried searching for the tag [php](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5bphp%5d%20is%3aq) or [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5bjavascript%5d%20is%3aq). I did not find a tag on this site for which I would get mixed-tag question on the first page of this search before single-tagged questions. (But I have only tried a few tags.)

Comment: Here is a SEDE query which lists a bit more details about the questions: https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1238960/finding-questions-having-only-the-given-tag?tagname=calculus